# Cycle2's scrollHorz doesn't work smoothly on fullscreen images

Tags: slideshow, carousel, jquery-cycle2

I'm currently using Cycle2 with scrollHorz on full screen (100% width and height) with background images with their size to 'cover', besides that there are no callbacks or much else on the page so its a very basic slider.

I find that when the browser is too big, the slide transition appears jagged, not smooth. However its somewhat better when the screen is smaller. I also do not experience any issues with 'fade', or at least its not noticeable at all.

I have tried with various combination of easing and speed, but haven't had much luck.

I'm not sure if its a css thing or a cycle2 thing, and I'm unable to find a similar issue via google, can someone please shed some light to this?

**HTML**

```
<ul id="homepage-carousel" class="hero">
    <li class="homepage-carousel-item" style="background-image: url('hero1.jpg');">
        <div class="homepage-carousel-info">
            <h1 class="homepage-carousel-title">Title</h1>              
            <h2 class="homepage-carousel-subtitle">Subtitle</h2>                
            <div class="homepage-carousel-desc">
                <p>some info here</p>
            </div>                                  
            <div class="homepage-carousel-link"><a class="homepage-carousel-url" href="#" title=""><span>Read More</span></a></div> 
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="homepage-carousel-item" style="background-image: url('hero2.jpg');">
        <div class="homepage-carousel-info">
            <h1 class="homepage-carousel-title">Title</h1>              
            <h2 class="homepage-carousel-subtitle">Subtitle</h2>                
            <div class="homepage-carousel-desc">
                <p>some info here</p>
            </div>                                  
            <div class="homepage-carousel-link"><a class="homepage-carousel-url" href="#" title=""><span>Read More</span></a></div> 
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="homepage-carousel-item" style="background-image: url('hero3.jpg');">
        <div class="homepage-carousel-info">
            <h1 class="homepage-carousel-title">Title</h1>              
            <h2 class="homepage-carousel-subtitle">Subtitle</h2>                
            <div class="homepage-carousel-desc">
                <p>some info here</p>
            </div>                                  
            <div class="homepage-carousel-link"><a class="homepage-carousel-url" href="#" title=""><span>Read More</span></a></div> 
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#homepage-carousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    .homepage-carousel-item {
        height: 100%;
        background-repeat: none;
        background-position: top center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This isn't a cycle issue**

`background-size: cover` just has horrible performance.

You can ease the pain some by adding `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` to the slides as well, but it will still be choppy.

Replacing the background with an actual image normally increases the performance for me, like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/coh4runn/). Though, the larger the image is the slower the performance will be in any browser; rendering large moving images is hard for them.

Then it's just a matter of sizing and positioning the images, for that you could use something like:

```
.homepage-carousel-item > img, .homepage-carousel-info { position:absolute; }
.homepage-carousel-item > img {
    /*img size*/
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    /*img pos*/
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);/*offset position based on img size*/
}
```

If you need to support legacy browsers, then you would run a routine through the images to size and offset [like this does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776670/how-to-emulate-background-size-cover-on-img/19777110#19777110).

There are other solutions that only work in certain browsers (like `object-fit: cover`), but these options should work in all browsers.