# Mimic the css background cover img property in html

Tags: jquery, html, background-image, cover

Thanks all for your responses. However, I haven't found any good answer to my question. So let me be more clear.

**PURPOSE**

As I'm working on SEO, I need to include images as html elements and mimic all the css attributes.

**What I currently have**

I added images within the css in order to expand/stretch and always center them in the middle of a div.

```
.page-electricite-generale .one {
    background: url('assets/images/elec/XXXX.jpg') 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[Here is a jsfidle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ync70trw/)

As you can see, the center of the image is always centered, without any crop/distortion inside the div.

**What I need**

I want to integrate images as html element and mimic the previous jsfidle.

[Here is the jsfidle with an html image](http://jsfiddle.net/773hcof2/2/)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to emulate background-size: cover on <img>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776670/how-to-emulate-background-size-cover-on-img).

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Is there an equivalent to background-size: cover and contain for image elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670874/is-there-an-equivalent-to-background-size-cover-and-contain-for-image-elements)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the two examples are not centering the image in the midle of the div. Let me do a jsfidle as example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several possible solutions:

**1. Combine  tag and background image**

This one is easiest. You put image in your markup like you would normally but hide it and use background-image on parent element. All modern browsers will download your image only once and cache it so you don't need to worry about performance. Just mind your image has correct path depending on file.

Example:

```
<div class="img-holder">
  <img class="hidden" src="/assets/images/elec/XXXX.jpg" />
</div>


.hidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

.img-holder {
    background: url(assets/images/elec/XXXX.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    // define your container width and height
}
```

**2. CSS hacks**

Check out this article: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

There are several techniques listed there. This one worked for me:

```
.parent {
  position: absolute; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}

.parent img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

**3. Object-fit property**

```
img { object-fit: cover; }
```

This is new property that is basically `background-size` version for images in markup. Unfortunately, browser support is not there yet.

Resources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit
http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
elem.prepend(
    $("<img />", {
        "src":"assets/images/elec/XXXX.jpg",
        "width":elem.css("width"),
        "height":elem.css("height"),
        "css": {
            "position":"relative",
            "left":((parseInt(elem.parent().css("width")) 
                   - parseInt(elem.css("width"))) / 2) + "px"
        }
    })
);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/th2LefL1/

Comment: The center tag has been depreciated, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html, though I think it may still work in some browsers

Comment: This will adjust the image with the height and the width, but it won't mimic this css line: background: url('assets/images/elec/XXXX.jpg') 50% 50% no-repeat;
here we are adjusting the height or the width and also, we are centering the image from it's center so we won't see any blank or distortion

Answer (score 1):

Its not perfect, but I think you may be able to do something like this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fmj7v1q9/1)**

```js
 function back() {
   var h = $('img').parent().height(),
     w = $('img').parent().width();

   if (w <= h) {
     $('img').each(function() {
       $(this).css({
         height: $(this).parent().height(),
         minHeight: $(this).parent().height(),
         minWidth: $(this).parent().width(),
         width: 'auto'
       });
     });
   } else {
     $('img').each(function() {
       $(this).css({
         width: $(this).parent().width(),
         minHeight: $(this).parent().height(),
         minWidth: $(this).parent().width(),
         height: 'auto'
       });
     });
   }
 };

 $(window).load(back());
 $(window).resize(function() {
   back();
 });
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
.cover {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNQ2g.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / cover transparent;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNQ2g.png" alt="example" title="example" />
</div>
<div class="cover"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an HTML `<img>` tag, and pure CSS to resize the image.  This way you have the image as an HTML element for SEO purposes, but you don't have to use JavaScript to responsively change the size.

HTML

```
<img src='assets/images/elec/XXXX.jpg'>
```

CSS

```
img.bg {
/* Set rules to fill background */
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 1024px;

/* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

/* Set up positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
    img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty smart, however, all images have different size and I would like to find a solution that I can easily copy and past accross projects and with different images

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the image is at least as large as it's container, you can just use (assuming the style applies to an IMG element)

```
.page-electricite-generale .one {
    max-width: 100%
    max-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```